# União entre vetores em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou com uma duvida nesse código pois a função deveria imprimir {1,2,3} porém imprimi {1,2,3,4,10,24,73}

```
void uniao(int A[], int B[], int C[]){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO ; i++){
    if (A[i] == 1){
        C[i] = A[i];    
    }
    if (B[i] == 1){
        C[i] = B[i];    
    }
}
```

}

A função imprimir que usei foi:

```
void imprimir( int vet[], int tam) {
int i;

for (i = 0 ; i < tam ; i++){
    if( vet[i] == 1){
        printf("Conjuntos: %d \n",i );  
    }

}
```

}

main do cod:

```
int A[TAMANHO] = {0,0,1,1};
int B[TAMANHO] = {0,1,1,1};
int C[TAMANHO];


uniao(A,B,C);
imprimir(C,TAMANHO);
```

Comment: Aqui: http://ideone.com/NwHEA4 funcionou corretamente.

Comment: ei, realmente funciona adicionando o tamanho como 4, mas eu preciso adicionar o tamanho como 200. E quando faço isso continua imprimindo os numeros 10,24 e 73.

Comment: Mas quando você informa tamanho 200 você informa os 200 valores de cada um dos vetores?

Comment: não, esse tamanho é apenas o que é pedido no enunciado da questão (que eu nao entendi muito bem, por isso estou cheio de duvidas). No caso as funções tem que ser bem genéricas pois serão testadas em outros programas.

Comment: Neste caso é melhor colocar o tamanho dos vetores como parâmetro também na função uniao.

Comment: Agora uma observação: pelo que entendo de união sua função não faz a união dos vetores.

Comment: Acho que ta tudo muito confuso, principalmente no meu entendimento deste trabalho (algumas funções estou usando as ja fornecidas pelo professor). Mas obrigaso por tentar me ajudar ;)

Comment: quando voc e muda o tamanho pra 200, como você inicializa os vetores A e B?
é melhor voce coloar o código todo aí, em vez de pedacinhos que não podem ser executados por quem está vendo a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o vetor `C` não está sendo inicializado. Isso quer dizer que da maneira que está implementado ele está recebendo valores "aleatórios" da memória e para resolver isso você precisa primeiro inicializá-lo.

Existem diversas maneiras de se inicializar um vetor, mas para este exemplo eu vou mostrar a mais explícita, com um laço:

```c
int C[TAMANHO];

for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
    C[i] = 0;
}
```

Dessa forma o resultado vai ser sempre determinado e seu exemplo vai ser executado conforme esperado.

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar, mas ue consegui resolver os problemas deste código, agradeço :)